# Javascript XPath href console.log object Attr output

Tags: javascript, xpath, nodes, element

Hey all I am looking to get the **href** link from some html using the **Xpath** like so:

```
function getStuff(Path) {
  var txt = '';
  var cnt = 0;
  var nodes = document.evaluate(Path, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
  var result = nodes.iterateNext();
  var Json = '{testing:[';
  while (result) {
    if (cnt != 10) {
      //console.log('Result: ', result);
      txt += '{href:' + result + '},';
      result = nodes.iterateNext();
      cnt++;
    } else {
      txt = txt.replace(/(^,)|(,$)/g, );
      break;
    }
  }
  return Json + txt + ']}';
}
console.log(getStuff("//html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/descendant::a[contains(@href, '?fref=pb')]/@href"));
```

The output looks like this:

```
{testing:[{href:[object Attr]},{href:[object Attr]},{href:[object A...etc etc
```

However, if I un-comment the `console.log` it outputs like I need it to:

```
Result:  href=​"/​bob.barker.982?fref=pb"
Result:  href=​"/​bill.gates.982?fref=pb"
Result:  href=​"/​steve.jobs?fref=pb"
Result:  href=​"/513845713656?fref=pb"
Result:  href=​"/​bill.murry?fref=pb"
Result:  href=​"/​m.c.hammer?fref=pb"
...etc etc
```

How can I get that same output that `console.log` has but saved to the `txt+=` logic? And if there is a better way of doing this then please do share.

Here is the [JSfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/stealthrt/d2sern09/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `result` is an [Attr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Attr) so you should use `result.value`

You can also simplify this using by building a real array and [stringifying](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) the result. **Never** build your own JSON strings

```js
function getStuff(path) {
  const nodes = document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
  const result = {
    testing: []
  }
  
  let i = 0
  let attr = nodes.iterateNext()
  while (i++ < 10 && attr) {
    result.testing.push({ href: attr.value })
    attr = nodes.iterateNext()
  }

  // remove the last 2 args if you don't want formatting
  return JSON.stringify(result, null, 2) 
}
console.log(getStuff("//html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/descendant::a[contains(@href, '?fref=pb')]/@href"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<div id="main"> <div class="a" style="min-height: 480px;"> <div class="72"> <div class="4"> <div class="5"> <div> <div class="o"> <div> <div class="qr"> <div class="item"> <div class="ib"> <a class="l" href="/bob.barker.982?fref=pb"></a> <div class="n"> <a href="/bob.barker.982?fref=pb"> <div class="t5"> <span> <span> <strong>bob barker</strong> </span> </span> </div></a> <div class="p"> <div class="0" id="u0c"> <div class="9" style="display: none;">something here</div><div style="display: none;" class="notice">something here</div><div class="notice ellipsis"></div><div style="display: none;" class="nce">something here</div></div></div></div><div class="4m" id="u0F"> <a href="/link/here/4jjk5rtgjrtujyerth" class="g"> <i class="gQ"> <u>someething here</u> </i> <span class="_55sr">something here</span></a> </div></div></div></div><div class="qr"> <div class="item"> <div class="ib"> <a class="l" href="/bill.gates.982?fref=pb"></a> <div class="n"> <a href="/bill.gates.982?fref=pb"> <div class="t5"> <span> <span> <strong>bill gates</strong> </span> </span> </div></a> <div class="p"> <div class="0" id="u0c"> <div class="9" style="display: none;">something here</div><div style="display: none;" class="notice">something here</div><div class="notice ellipsis"></div><div style="display: none;" class="nce">something here</div></div></div></div><div class="4m" id="u0F"> <a href="/link/here/4jjk5rtgjrtujyerth" class="g"> <i class="gQ"> <u>someething here</u> </i> <span class="_55sr">something here</span></a> </div></div></div></div><div class="qr"> <div class="item"> <div class="ib"> <a class="l" href="/steve.jobs.982?fref=pb"></a> <div class="n"> <a href="/steve.jobs.982?fref=pb"> <div class="t5"> <span> <span> <strong>steve jobs</strong> </span> </span> </div></a> <div class="p"> <div class="0" id="u0c"> <div class="9" style="display: none;">something here</div><div style="display: none;" class="notice">something here</div><div class="notice ellipsis"></div><div style="display: none;" class="nce">something here</div></div></div></div><div class="4m" id="u0F"> <a href="/link/here/4jjk5rtgjrtujyerth" class="g"> <i class="gQ"> <u>someething here</u> </i> <span class="_55sr">something here</span></a> </div></div></div></div><div class="qr"> <div class="item"> <div class="ib"> <a class="l" href="/513845713656.982?fref=pb"></a> <div class="n"> <a href="/513845713656.982?fref=pb"> <div class="t5"> <span> <span> <strong>513845713656</strong> </span> </span> </div></a> <div class="p"> <div class="0" id="u0c"> <div class="9" style="display: none;">something here</div><div style="display: none;" class="notice">something here</div><div class="notice ellipsis"></div><div style="display: none;" class="nce">something here</div></div></div></div><div class="4m" id="u0F"> <a href="/link/here/4jjk5rtgjrtujyerth" class="g"> <i class="gQ"> <u>someething here</u> </i> <span class="_55sr">something here</span></a> </div></div></div></div><div class="qr"> <div class="item"> <div class="ib"> <a class="l" href="/bill.murrey.982?fref=pb"></a> <div class="n"> <a href="/bill.murrey.982?fref=pb"> <div class="t5"> <span> <span> <strong>bill murrey</strong> </span> </span> </div></a> <div class="p"> <div class="0" id="u0c"> <div class="9" style="display: none;">something here</div><div style="display: none;" class="notice">something here</div><div class="notice ellipsis"></div><div style="display: none;" class="nce">something here</div></div></div></div><div class="4m" id="u0F"> <a href="/link/here/4jjk5rtgjrtujyerth" class="g"> <i class="gQ"> <u>someething here</u> </i> <span class="_55sr">something here</span></a> </div></div></div></div><div class="qr"> <div class="item"> <div class="ib"> <a class="l" href="/m.c.hammer.982?fref=pb"></a> <div class="n"> <a href="/m.c.hammer.982?fref=pb"> <div class="t5"> <span> <span> <strong>m.c.hammer</strong> </span> </span> </div></a> <div class="p"> <div class="0" id="u0c"> <div class="9" style="display: none;">something here</div><div style="display: none;" class="notice">something here</div><div class="notice ellipsis"></div><div style="display: none;" class="nce">something here</div></div></div></div><div class="4m" id="u0F"> <a href="/link/here/4jjk5rtgjrtujyerth" class="g"> <i class="gQ"> <u>someething here</u> </i> <span class="_55sr">something here</span></a> </div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div id="outcome" style="font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold;">Open Dev Tools > console for output</div>
```

Comment: Great example there @Phil. That worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem. The developer console is logging `Attribute` objects. You need to find a way to turn the attribute into a string, like so:

```
txt += '{href:' + result.value + '},';
```

You might also want to do:

```
txt += '{href: \"' + result.value + '\"},';
```